# how to check unique name when column name and param name is different

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 8. my parameter name is `phone` but my column name is mobile.

```
$validator = $request->validate([
        'phone' => ['required', Rule::unique('profiles','mobile'),new Mobile],
    ]);
```

but it doesn't check unique of it.

my `mobile` rule:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Rules;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
    
    class Mobile implements Rule
    {
        /**
         * Create a new rule instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }
    
        /**
         * Determine if the validation rule passes.
         *
         * @param  string  $attribute
         * @param  mixed  $value
         * @return bool
         */
        public function passes($attribute, $value)
        {
            if(preg_match('/^(09)[0-9]{9}$/',$value))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation error message.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function message()
        {
            return 'it's not correct';
        }
    }
```

Comment: `new Mobile` is this your custom validation?? it doesn't comply with any validation rules.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon updated my question.

Comment: what do you get if you try without the Rule class??

Comment: @S.M_Emamian are you sure you have mobile number which your checking otherwise validation rule correct .no issues. initially i misunderstood your question. Also your custom rule also correct. also make sure mobile number shouldnt have space at the end or beginning

Comment: @S.M_Emamian can you show screenshot of database table with data .for which you tried uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
'custom_param'=>'required|unique:table_name,colum_name'
```

Replacing in your example

```
'phone'=>'required|unique:profiles,mobile'
```

Follow the documentation for more information, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)